# Count specific word in txt file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, word-count

How do I count a specific word in a specific text file ussing vb.net

Comment: Load it into a string variable then do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121907/count-words-in-visual-basic in conjunction with `"\bFind Me\b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would help you:

```
Private Function GetWordCountInFile(ByVal filepath As String, ByVal word As String)
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath).Split(" "))

    For Each entry As String In lst
        If Not (dict.ContainsKey(entry.ToLower.Trim)) Then
            dict.Add(entry.ToLower.Trim, 1)
        Else
            dict(entry.ToLower.Trim) += 1
        End If
    Next
    lst.Clear()
    Return dict(word.ToLower.Trim)
End Function
```

you can use it like this:

```
   Dim count As Integer = GetWordCountInFile("../../Sample.txt", "sample")
```

This will look for a word "sample" in a text file "sample.txt" and returns a count.

Also, may not a good one but a single line approach would be:

```
Private Function GetWordCountInFile(ByVal filepath As String, ByVal word As String)
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath), "(?i)\b(\s+)?" & word & "(\s+|\S{0})\b|^" & word & "\.?$|" & word & "[\.\,\;]").Count
End Function
```

OR something like this: (no need to declare additional variable to hold word count)

```
   Private Function GetWordCountInFile(ByVal filepath As String, ByVal word As String)
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath).ToLower.Split(New Char() {" ", ",", ";", ".", ":"}))
    Return lst.FindAll(Function(c) c.Trim() = word.ToLower).Count()
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 4.0...

The word must be an exact match (excluding mixed case).  If you want to count matching sub-words, such as searching for "sub" and counting "subway" as a word, change to LCase(strWord).Contains(LCase("TargetWord"))...

```
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt").Split(" ").ToList().ForEach(Sub(strWord As String)
                                                                       If LCase(strWord) = LCase("TargetWord") Then
                                                                           intCount += 1
                                                                       End If
                                                                   End Sub)
    MsgBox(CStr(intCount))
```